# Getting "Ranch protocol" when accessing all routes in Phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've created a brand new Phoenix app with `mix phx.new my_app` and did all the usual steps, then generated a new model with `mix phx.gen.json ...`. Everything seemed to be working when I went to `/api/my_json_resource` and so I committed it and moved on, but now after changing nothing when I restart the server and try to go to any route I get the following error:

```
[error] Ranch protocol :error of listener MyAppWeb.Endpoint.HTTP (cowboy_protocol) terminated
** (exit) :undef
```

Elixir version: Elixir 1.7.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)

deps:

```
  {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.4"},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.10"},
  {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by running `rm -rf _build`.